# How can user resize control at runtime in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Say i have a pictureBox.

Now what i want is that user should be able to resize the pictureBox at will. However i have no idea on how to even start on this thing. I have searched internet however information is scarce.

Can anybody at least guide me on where to start ?

Answer (score 43):

This is pretty easy to do, every window in Windows has the innate ability to be resizable.  It is just turned off for a PictureBox, you can turn it back on by listening for the [WM_NCHITTEST message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You simply tell Windows that the cursor is on a corner of a window, you get everything else for free.  You'll also want to draw a grab handle so it is clear to the user that dragging the corner will resize the box.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Build + Build.  You'll get a new control on top of the toolbox, drop it on a form.  Set the Image property and you're set to try it.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class SizeablePictureBox : PictureBox {
    public SizeablePictureBox() {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var rc = new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - grab, this.ClientSize.Height - grab, grab, grab);
        ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, this.BackColor, rc); 
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) {  // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
            var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
            if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - grab && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - grab)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(17);  // HT_BOTTOMRIGHT
        }
    }
    private const int grab = 16;
}
```

Another *very* cheap way to get the resizing for free is by giving the control a resizable border.  Which works on all corners and edges.  Paste this code into the class (you don't need WndProc anymore):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= 0x840000;  // Turn on WS_BORDER + WS_THICKFRAME
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so now i am able to resize the control at runtime. However the resize handle only appears in the bottom right corner of the control. Is there any way that i can resize the control from anywhere i want sort of like we do in visual studio when placing controls.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. In regard to the limitation mentioned by @WinCoder, you can resize from any side of the control with the second solution if the value `0x840000` is replaced with `0x00040000` in the line `cp.Style |= 0x840000;`. This sets the style to WS_SIZEBOX . [Reference Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 6):

with use ControlMoverOrResizer class in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709121/Move-and-resize-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime-with) you can do movable and resizable controls in run time just with a line of code! :) example:

ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(button1);

and now button1 is a movable and resizable control!

Answer (score 4):

here is an article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20716/Allow-the-User-to-Resize-Controls-at-Runtime

that should help you since it in vb here a C# translation

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Form1
{


    ResizeableControl rc;

    private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        rc = new ResizeableControl(pbDemo);

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

}
```

AND RE-SIZE FUNCTION

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class ResizeableControl
{

    private Control withEventsField_mControl;
    private Control mControl {
        get { return withEventsField_mControl; }
        set {
            if (withEventsField_mControl != null) {
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseDown -= mControl_MouseDown;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseUp -= mControl_MouseUp;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseMove -= mControl_MouseMove;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseLeave -= mControl_MouseLeave;
            }
            withEventsField_mControl = value;
            if (withEventsField_mControl != null) {
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseDown += mControl_MouseDown;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseUp += mControl_MouseUp;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseMove += mControl_MouseMove;
                withEventsField_mControl.MouseLeave += mControl_MouseLeave;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool mMouseDown = false;
    private EdgeEnum mEdge = EdgeEnum.None;
    private int mWidth = 4;

    private bool mOutlineDrawn = false;
    private enum EdgeEnum
    {
        None,
        Right,
        Left,
        Top,
        Bottom,
        TopLeft
    }

    public ResizeableControl(Control Control)
    {
        mControl = Control;
    }


    private void mControl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) {
            mMouseDown = true;
        }
    }


    private void mControl_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mMouseDown = false;
    }


    private void mControl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = (Control)sender;
        Graphics g = c.CreateGraphics;
        switch (mEdge) {
            case EdgeEnum.TopLeft:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, 0, 0, mWidth * 4, mWidth * 4);
                mOutlineDrawn = true;
                break;
            case EdgeEnum.Left:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, 0, 0, mWidth, c.Height);
                mOutlineDrawn = true;
                break;
            case EdgeEnum.Right:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, c.Width - mWidth, 0, c.Width, c.Height);
                mOutlineDrawn = true;
                break;
            case EdgeEnum.Top:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, 0, 0, c.Width, mWidth);
                mOutlineDrawn = true;
                break;
            case EdgeEnum.Bottom:
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, 0, c.Height - mWidth, c.Width, mWidth);
                mOutlineDrawn = true;
                break;
            case EdgeEnum.None:
                if (mOutlineDrawn) {
                    c.Refresh();
                    mOutlineDrawn = false;
                }
                break;
        }

        if (mMouseDown & mEdge != EdgeEnum.None) {
            c.SuspendLayout();
            switch (mEdge) {
                case EdgeEnum.TopLeft:
                    c.SetBounds(c.Left + e.X, c.Top + e.Y, c.Width, c.Height);
                    break;
                case EdgeEnum.Left:
                    c.SetBounds(c.Left + e.X, c.Top, c.Width - e.X, c.Height);
                    break;
                case EdgeEnum.Right:
                    c.SetBounds(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width - (c.Width - e.X), c.Height);
                    break;
                case EdgeEnum.Top:
                    c.SetBounds(c.Left, c.Top + e.Y, c.Width, c.Height - e.Y);
                    break;
                case EdgeEnum.Bottom:
                    c.SetBounds(c.Left, c.Top, c.Width, c.Height - (c.Height - e.Y));
                    break;
            }
            c.ResumeLayout();
        } else {
            switch (true) {
                case e.X <= (mWidth * 4) & e.Y <= (mWidth * 4):
                    //top left corner
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.TopLeft;
                    break;
                case e.X <= mWidth:
                    //left edge
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.VSplit;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.Left;
                    break;
                case e.X > c.Width - (mWidth + 1):
                    //right edge
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.VSplit;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.Right;
                    break;
                case e.Y <= mWidth:
                    //top edge
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.HSplit;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.Top;
                    break;
                case e.Y > c.Height - (mWidth + 1):
                    //bottom edge
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.HSplit;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.Bottom;
                    break;
                default:
                    //no edge
                    c.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    mEdge = EdgeEnum.None;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    private void mControl_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = (Control)sender;
        mEdge = EdgeEnum.None;
        c.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well i would have preferred implementing my own solution but by the looks of the code it seems beyond my capability to implement such a thing.

Comment: it not as simple as it may sound because since you doing it at run-time you have to update the control at run-time and track the points i think this solution is simple

Comment: i would really prefer to implement my own solution is it easier to do in XAML ?

Comment: Sorry, the class doesn't work as far as I can tell as the switch near the end has designtime errors with each case

Comment: Could you please try and revise your code here? Seems you put some work into it, but it fails like this - even when I replace the failing Case statements with if, else if... blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new c# winform application and paste this:

Don't forget to say thanks when it help you...

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=743923&av=1095793&msg=4778687

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
 public partial class MyForm : Form
  {
    //Public Declaration:
    double rW = 0;
    double rH = 0;

    int fH = 0;
    int fW = 0;


    // @ Form Initialization
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += MyForm_Resize; // handles resize routine
        this.tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.None;

    }


    private void MyForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rResize(this,true); //Call the routine

    }

    private void rResize(Control t, bool hasTabs) // Routine to Auto resize the control
    {

        // this will return to normal default size when 1 of the conditions is met

        string[] s = null;

        if (this.Width < fW || this.Height < fH)
        {

            this.Width = (int)fW;
            this.Height = (int)fH;

            return;
        }

        foreach (Control c in t.Controls)
        {
            // Option 1:
            double rRW = (t.Width > rW ? t.Width / (rW) : rW / t.Width);
            double rRH = (t.Height > rH ? t.Height / (rH) : rH / t.Height);

            // Option 2:
            //  double rRW = t.Width / rW;
            //  double rRH = t.Height / rH;

            s = c.Tag.ToString().Split('/');
            if (c.Name == s[0].ToString())
            {
                //Use integer casting
                c.Width = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[3]) * rRW);
                c.Height = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[4]) * rRH);
                c.Left = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[1]) * rRW);
                c.Top = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[2]) * rRH);
            }
            if (hasTabs)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(TabControl))
                {

                    foreach (Control f in c.Controls)
                    {
                        foreach (Control j in f.Controls) //tabpage
                        {
                            s = j.Tag.ToString().Split('/');

                            if (j.Name == s[0].ToString())
                            {

                                j.Width = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[3]) * rRW);
                                j.Height = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[4]) * rRH);
                                j.Left = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[1]) * rRW);
                                j.Top = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(s[2]) * rRH);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // @ Form Load Event
    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Put values in the variables

        rW = this.Width;
        rH = this.Height;

        fW = this.Width;
        fH = this.Height;


        // Loop through the controls inside the  form i.e. Tabcontrol Container
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            c.Tag = c.Name + "/" + c.Left + "/" + c.Top + "/" + c.Width + "/" + c.Height;

            // c.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Right |  AnchorStyles.Left ); 

            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TabControl))
            {

                foreach (Control f in c.Controls)
                {

                    foreach (Control j in f.Controls) //tabpage
                    {
                        j.Tag = j.Name + "/" + j.Left + "/" + j.Top + "/" + j.Width + "/" + j.Height;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Regards,
Kix46

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace utils
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Drawing;
public static class Helper
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HTCAPTION = 2;
    public static int WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    public static int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    public const int WS_RESIZABLE = 0x840000; //WS_BORDER + WS_THICKFRAME

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uFlags, uint uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr Handle, int Clr, byte transparency, int clrkey);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);

    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
    public static string ProcessException(this Exception ex)
    {
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder(5000);
        Exception inner = ex;
        Enumerable.Range(0, 30).All(x =>
        {
            if (x == 0) strBuild.Append("########## Exception begin on thread id : " + GetCurrentThreadId().ToString() + " @ :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ##########\n");
            strBuild.Append("---------------------[" + x.ToString() + "]---------------------\n");
            strBuild.Append("Message : " + inner.Message + "\nStack Trace : " + inner.StackTrace + "\n");
            strBuild.Append("---------------------[" + x.ToString() + "]---------------------\n");
            inner = inner.InnerException;
            if (inner == null)
            {
                strBuild.Append("########## Exception End on thread id : " + GetCurrentThreadId().ToString() + " @ :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ##########\n\n");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        return strBuild.ToString();
    }
   
   public static void MakeResizable(this Panel pnl)
    {
        int dwCurStyle = Helper.GetWindowLong(pnl.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
        dwCurStyle = dwCurStyle | Helper.WS_RESIZABLE;
        Helper.SetWindowLong(pnl.Handle, GWL_STYLE, dwCurStyle);
    }
}

 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        imagePanel.MakeResizable();
        base.OnLoad(e);            
    }
```

where imgPanel is some Panel in the WinForm App

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my win form application

```
public partial class logoPosition : Form
    {
        bool Draggable = false, ResizableH = false, ResizableW = false;
        int XOffset = 0, YOffset = 0;
        public logoPosition()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void logoPosition_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image logo = new Bitmap(@"\Sign_Transparent.png");
            PBLogo.Image = logo;
            PBLogo.Margin = new Padding(3);
            PBLogo.Location = new Point(3, 3);
            PBLogo.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            PBLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            txtW.Text = PBLogo.Width.ToString();
            txtH.Text = PBLogo.Height.ToString();
            txtX.Text = PBLogo.Location.X.ToString();
            txtY.Text = PBLogo.Location.Y.ToString();
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PBLogo.Margin = new Padding(3);
            PBLogo.Location = new Point(3, 3);
            PBLogo.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            PBLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            PBLogo.Height = 50;
            PBLogo.Width = 100;
        }

        private void PBLogo_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            //set location for PictureBox bottom side;
            Rectangle recBottomSide = new Rectangle(0 ,  PBLogo.Height-3, PBLogo.Width,10);
            //set location for PictureBox right side;
            Rectangle recRightSide = new Rectangle(PBLogo.Width-3, 0, 10, PBLogo.Height);
            

            if (recBottomSide.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                PBLogo.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
            }
            else if(recRightSide.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                PBLogo.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
            }
            else
            {
                PBLogo.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
            }

            int XMoved = e.Location.X - XOffset;
            int YMoved = e.Location.Y - YOffset;
            Point newPosition = new Point();

            if (Draggable)
            {

                newPosition.X = PBLogo.Location.X + XMoved;
                newPosition.Y = PBLogo.Location.Y + YMoved;

                if (newPosition.X + PBLogo.Width >= panel1.Width || newPosition.X <= 0)
                    newPosition.X = PBLogo.Location.X;
                if (newPosition.Y + PBLogo.Height > panel1.Height || newPosition.Y <= 0)
                    newPosition.Y = PBLogo.Location.Y;

                PBLogo.Location = newPosition;
                
            }
            if(ResizableH)
            {
                if (PBLogo.Location.Y + e.Y < panel1.Height)
                {
                    PBLogo.Height = e.Y;
                    if (PBLogo.Height < 30) PBLogo.Height = 30;
                }
            }
            if(ResizableW)
            {
                if (PBLogo.Location.X + e.X < panel1.Width)
                {
                    PBLogo.Width = e.X;
                    if (PBLogo.Width < 30) PBLogo.Width = 30;
                }
            }


            txtW.Text = PBLogo.Width.ToString();
            txtH.Text = PBLogo.Height.ToString();
            txtX.Text = PBLogo.Location.X.ToString();
            txtY.Text = PBLogo.Location.Y.ToString();

            

            
        }

        private void PBLogo_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            XOffset = e.X;
            YOffset = e.Y;

            if (PBLogo.Cursor == Cursors.SizeAll)
            {
                Draggable = true;
                ResizableW = false;
                ResizableH = false;
            }
            if(PBLogo.Cursor == Cursors.SizeNS)
            {
                Draggable = false;
                ResizableW = false;
                ResizableH = true;
            }
            if (PBLogo.Cursor == Cursors.SizeWE)
            {
                Draggable = false;
                ResizableW = true;
                ResizableH = false;
            }

        }

        private void PBLogo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Draggable = false;
            ResizableW = false;
            ResizableH = false;
        }
    }
```