# C# FORMS, Rezising a picturebox at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I am trying to rezise a picturebox at runtime, and I've found some code that others have gotten to work. The code came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264225/how-can-user-resize-control-at-runtime-in-winforms), but I will just copy paste here as well.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
get {
    var cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.Style |= 0x840000;  // Turn on WS_BORDER + WS_THICKFRAME
    return cp;
}
}
```

According to the answer, I just have to paste that into my class, but what class? I don't know where to paste it to get my picturebox resizing to work, and was hoping someone here could clarify what he ment.

Thanks

Comment: Create a new class inheriting from `PictureBox` and override its `CreatePrams` this way. But I believe the other solution of that post, overriding `WndProc` and processing `WM_NCHITTEST` is better, as also mentioned by the author (Hans).

Comment: Into SizeablePictureBox.  As an alternative for OnPaint + WndProc.  Just try it both ways to see what you like.

Comment: So SizeablePictureBox has the exact same properties of a normal PictureBox, except it can be rezised at runtime?                                                        Edit: I've got it working perfectly now, but I was hoping to find a way to also move the entire image, just like when you're designing your forms.

Comment: [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) *When you define a class to derive from another class, the derived class implicitly gains all the members of the base class, except for its constructors and destructors.*

Comment: I see. Thanks!                                                                                                        Is there a way to modify the code to include dragging from bottom left corner too, or moving the entire image? Either of those 2 work.

Comment: To be able to change size use `cp.Style |= 0x040000;` For moving you should follow `WndProc` approach.

Comment: I'm using the first solution in the link, which doesn't include cp.Style, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should check for [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx) in `WndProc` and then based on mouse position, return suitable `HT` result.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new class which inheirt from pictureBox class and copy code there
Then drag your newly created control from ToolBox to form, and that should be it.

If control is missing from the toolbox, you should rebuild your project.
Im using same code and it is working perfectly :)
Hope it helps