# Is it possible to create by user in runtime controls (button,image) that has a resizer frame designtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to create by user in runtime controls (button,image) that has a resizer frame designtime?
The controls can be resizing like in designtime. Not hide the frame from designer.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you need exactly. Am i correct when i think you want to be able to resize controls created dynamically from code in runtime on your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create new controls based on the original control you want to be able to resize (inheritence) and make them resizable.

Look at this:

[How can user resize control at runtime in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264225/how-can-user-resize-control-at-runtime-in-winforms)

Code: (from link above)

```
class SizeablePictureBox : PictureBox {
    public SizeablePictureBox() {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var rc = new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - grab, this.ClientSize.Height - grab, grab, grab);
        ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, this.BackColor, rc); 
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) {  // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
            var pos = this.PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));
            if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - grab && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - grab)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(17);  // HT_BOTTOMRIGHT
        }
    }
    private const int grab = 16;
}
```