# Resizable Controls with mouse - all directions - Problem with resizing to the minimum size of the control

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, controls, drag

I am implementing resizable controls on mouse drag. The problem is that the control that is panel in my case is resizing to the minimum size I have set which is good but when it is resized to the minimum size it begins moving to the side the mouse goes.

**My question** is how to prevent the panel from moving on resize when it reaches the minimum size that is set to.

**Problem**: The panel moves after the mouse when it reaches the minimum size.

I am using part of this code https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709121/Move-and-resize-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime-with

If you set minimum size to some of the panels in this example you can reproduce the problem I have.

The file with the source code in the article is made in Visual studio 2010 It says No Licence when I try to open it. I edited the **.sln** file in notepad and changed **# Visual Studio 2010** to # **Visual Studio 2019** and it can be opened in visual studio 2019.

**The modified Class from the Article:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Move_Resize_Controls
{
    class Move_Resize
    {
        // Event Sensors
        private static bool _moving;  
        private static bool _startMoveOrResize;  
        private static bool _resizing;
        private static Point _cursorStartPoint;
        private static Point _last_resize;
        private static Point _last_resize_location;
        private static Size _currentControlStartSize;


        // Edge Sensors
        private static bool MouseIsInLeftEdge { get; set; }
        private static bool MouseIsInRightEdge { get; set; }
        private static bool MouseIsInTopEdge { get; set; }
        private static bool MouseIsInBottomEdge { get; set; }

        // Control Settings
        internal static void Init(Control control, Control container)
        {
            _moving = false;
            _resizing = false;
            _cursorStartPoint = Point.Empty;
            MouseIsInLeftEdge = false;
            MouseIsInLeftEdge = false;
            MouseIsInRightEdge = false;
            MouseIsInTopEdge = false;
            MouseIsInBottomEdge = false;

            control.MouseMove += (sender, e) => MoveControl(container, e);
            control.MouseUp += (sender, e) => MouseUP_Control(container, e);
            control.MouseDown += (sender, e) => MouseDown_Control(container, e);
           
        }

        //:-:-:-: Events :-:-:-: ::START::----------------------------------------------------

         // ::Move::
         private static void MoveControl(Control control, MouseEventArgs e)
         {
         

            if(_startMoveOrResize != true)
            {
                //Edge Properties
                Update_Edge_Properties(control, new Point(e.X, e.Y)); // Check if cursor is in some of the Resize Region
                UpdateCursor(control); // Update the cursor Type "Cursor image"
            }

            else // If MouseDown == true
            {

                //Moving
                if ((MouseIsInLeftEdge || MouseIsInRightEdge || MouseIsInTopEdge || MouseIsInBottomEdge) == false ) // If mouse is not in resize area
                {
                    _moving = true; // Moving ís true

                    // Moving panel on Mouse Move
                    int X = (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X) + control.Left;
                    int Y = (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y) + control.Top;
                    control.Location = new Point(X,Y);  
                }


                // Resize
                else // if Mouse is down and it is in the resize area "Resize panel on mouse move"
                {

                    //control.Size == control.MinimumSize && control.Size.Width /*_currentControlStartSize.Width < control.Size.Width && _currentControlStartSize.Height < control.Size.Height &&*/


                    if (MouseIsInLeftEdge) // Left Side
                    {
                        if (MouseIsInTopEdge) // "Top Left Corner" Left Side and Top Side are only intersecting with eachother in the top left
                        {
                            control.Width -= (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);
                            control.Left += (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);
                            control.Height -= (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);
                            control.Top += (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);
                        }
                        else if (MouseIsInBottomEdge) // Bottom Left Corner
                        {

                            control.Width -= (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);
                            control.Left += (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);
                            control.Height = (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y) + _currentControlStartSize.Height;

                            
                        }
                        else // Left
                        {

                            if (control.Size.Width == control.MinimumSize.Width)
                            {
                                _last_resize_location = control.Location;

                            }


                            control.Width -= (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);
                            control.Left += (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X);


                            //Down
                            if (e.X < _last_resize.X && control.Size.Width == control.MinimumSize.Width)
                            {

                                control.BackColor = Color.Red;
                               

                            }

                            else if (e.X > _last_resize.X)
                            {

                                control.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                          
                              
                            }


                            _last_resize = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

                        }
                    }

                    else if (MouseIsInRightEdge) //Right
                    {
                        if (MouseIsInTopEdge)  // Top Right Corner
                        {
                            control.Width = (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X) + _currentControlStartSize.Width;
                            control.Height -= (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);
                            control.Top += (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);

                        }
                        else if (MouseIsInBottomEdge) //Bottom Right Corner
                        {
                            control.Width = (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X) + _currentControlStartSize.Width;
                            control.Height = (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y) + _currentControlStartSize.Height;
                        }
                        else // Right
                        {
                            control.Width = (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X) + _currentControlStartSize.Width;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (MouseIsInTopEdge) // Top
                    {
                        control.Height -= (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);
                        control.Top += (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y);
                    }
                    else if (MouseIsInBottomEdge) // Bottom
                    {
                        control.Height = (e.Y - _cursorStartPoint.Y) + _currentControlStartSize.Height;
                    }
                }


            }
         }
           
        // ::MouseUp::
        private static void MouseUP_Control(Control control, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            _moving = false;
            _resizing = false;
            _startMoveOrResize = false;
        }
       




        // ::MouseDown::
        private static void MouseDown_Control(Control control, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _currentControlStartSize = control.Size;
            _cursorStartPoint = e.Location;
            _startMoveOrResize = true;
        }


        //:-:-:-: Events :-:-:-: ::END::----------------------------------------------------





        // Update Edge Properties
        private static void Update_Edge_Properties(Control control, Point mouseLocationInControl)
        {

            if(_moving == true)
            {
                return;
            }


            MouseIsInLeftEdge = Math.Abs(mouseLocationInControl.X) <= 10; // Left
            MouseIsInRightEdge = Math.Abs(mouseLocationInControl.X - control.Width) <= 10; // Right
            MouseIsInTopEdge = Math.Abs(mouseLocationInControl.Y) <= 10; // Top
            MouseIsInBottomEdge = Math.Abs(mouseLocationInControl.Y - control.Height) <= 10; // Bottom
       
          
        }



 
        // Currsor Icon
        private static void UpdateCursor(Control control)
        {
            // If Moving "Return"   // Dont check for changing cursor image
            if(_moving == true)
            {
                return;
            }



            if (MouseIsInLeftEdge)
            {
                if (MouseIsInTopEdge)
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;   // Change Currsor type to Diagonal with two arrows
                }
                else if (MouseIsInBottomEdge)
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                }
            }



            else if (MouseIsInRightEdge)
            {
                if (MouseIsInTopEdge)
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW;
                }
                else if (MouseIsInBottomEdge)
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                }
            }


            else if (MouseIsInTopEdge || MouseIsInBottomEdge)
            {
                control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
            }
            else
            {
                control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [How can user resize control at runtime in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17264225/719186)

Comment: This one is more complete: [Creating Custom Picturebox with Draggable and Resizable Selection Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774101/7444103)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying both the "Create params" and the resize Frame but I cant figure out how to set minimum size to the control. It gets ignored in both solutions. Is there any way to set a minimum size to the control?

Comment: About the second code sample, you can add, in the `OnPaint` method, right before `base.OnPaint(e);`: `this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, this.Width); this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, this.Height);`

Comment: Or (probably better) override `OnResize` and move that code right after `base.OnResize(e);`.

Comment: Thanks, the minimum size works with the Second code sample, but I get the same error as before when it reaches the minimum size. The panel begins to move with the mouse when it reaches the minimum size. I am trying to achieve the function like on Form Window with minimum size. When I resize a Form Window with a minimum size it reaches the minimum size and stays steady and it does not move after the mouse when it reaches the minimum size.